# Some USB devices (ext CD-ROM, ext HDD) won't install drivers - Windows 7 64bit

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, usb, drivers

I have an external hard drive and external CD-ROM (USB devices) that work fine on other computers (specifically WinXP 32bit) and used to work on this computer (Win 7 64 bit) but do not now.  The built-in drivers do not apply to the devices.  I do have a third external drive that works and these drives that don't work on this Win7 box do work on my other computer.

I recently installed a SSD and installed a fresh OS load.  Also moved my user profile to a separate drive and linked it with mklink (used this instruction: http://www.starkeith.net/coredump/2009/05/18/how-to-move-your-windows-user-profile-to-another-drive/

Had to take ownership of some residual files to completely copy the profile. No problems. Everything works.. except my issue above.  I've tried MANY different solutions.  I assigned "Administrators" group as owner of the C:\Windows\inf directory.  I copied the inf directory into a new directory C:\USBDriver (with me as owner) and pointed to that for the driver, but still no go. I get an instant, low-pitch "do-do-do." I think I ruled out a permissions issue, but not positive on that.

I tried uninstalling in Dev Mgr and re-installing and updating driver without success. They are listed under "other device" and therefore do not show up in Disk Management.  Dev Mgr reports "The drivers for this device are not installed. (Code 28)."

I cannot uninstall the USB drivers because I use USB keyboard and mouse (been there, done that on previous load.)

Any ideas?

Comment: Update: I found the USB host controller that my KB/Mouse use and uninstalled all the others and rebooted. Still no luck. When I take the USB wireless receiver for my KB/mouse and plug it in to a different port, it fails like the others. When I plug the failing HD or CD-ROM into the 'good' port that the kb/mouse were plugged into, it fails. Ironically, a brand new USB thumb drive works fine in any port. If I were to go start assigning administrators or my user full control permissions in system folders, would that 'hurt' anything? I'd think it would just make it more vulnerable, but won't hurt?

Answer (score 0):

Look in the Device Manager on a machine where your devices work, and find out what drivers are in use. Then find the installation packages for those drivers, which should be sitting
in the DriverStore directory, and copy them over to your other machine, and use them to
install the drivers.

Comment: Would it matter that the laptop they work on is WinXP 32 bit and the desktop they don't work on is Win7 64 bit?

Answer (score 0):

I went ahead and rolled back with system restore, moved the profile back to the primary partition, and deleted the junction.  Works fine now.  Sorry, no solution for this issue.